# matchMedia to hide div on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I want to hide `navbar` only on mobile devices. It currently hides on any window size desktop/mobile. Is there something missing from my code?

**CSS**

```
.navbar-hide{transform: translateY(-100%);}
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  

 var isMobile = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)");
 if (isMobile.matches) {

 var header = $(".navbar");
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

 if (scroll >= 1200) {
 header.addClass("navbar-hide");
 } else {
 header.removeClass("navbar-hide");
 }

});

}

});
```

Comment: What is the css of .navbar class? You need e.g. `position:fixed; top: 0px;`

Comment: I'm using bootstrap. Like i said it already appends the class i just need it only do it on mobile.

Comment: Are you sure the element doesn't already have `navbar-hide` class on it in the markup, or added to it somewhere else?

Comment: Its not only the one i created (BS3)